# If column exists execute one query - otherwise perform the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to check if the column `VATNO` exists. If that column exists it is version 4.8 and then I want to perform that lookup. Otherwise it is an lower version then I want to perform the other query.

```
if exists(select * from sys.columns 
            where Name = N'VATNO' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'COMPANIES'))
BEGIN

/* If version is 4.8 */
SELECT [NO], [DESCRIPTION] FROM COMPANIES WHERE VATNO <> '' ORDER BY [NO]

END

ELSE
BEGIN

/* If under version 4.8 */
SELECT [NO], [DESCRIPTION] FROM COMPANIES ORDER BY [NO]

END ;
```

This returns the following error:

> Msg 207, level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'VATNO'

I am running SQL Server 10.50.1600

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: runs on MSSQL 10.0.4067 perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a compile time error. You will need to use dynamic SQL to resolve this.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000);
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE Name = N'VATNO' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'DBO.COMPANIES'))
BEGIN

/* If version is 4.8 */
SET @SQL = 'SELECT [NO], [DESCRIPTION] FROM COMPANIES WHERE VATNO <> '''' ORDER BY [NO]'

END

ELSE
BEGIN

/* If under version 4.8 */
SET @SQL = 'SELECT [NO], [DESCRIPTION] FROM COMPANIES ORDER BY [NO]'

END ;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Also, when calling `object_id()` it is a good practise to include schema

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL query is the way to get out of this situation:

```
IF ((SELECT count(name) FROM sys.columns WHERE name= 'VATNO') > 0)
BEGIN 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'  SELECT foobar FROM companies where VATNO <> '' ORDER BY [NO]';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
ELSE
begin
SELECT [NO], [DESCRIPTION] FROM COMPANIES ORDER BY [NO]
END;
```